# Has anyone installed ubuntu on sony vaio vpccw16fg?(cw 1 series)

Tags: system-installation, vaio, sony

1)please give your reviews(for those who have install it)

2)cant seem to find anything regarding ubuntu for sony vaio vpccw16fg on the web(succesful installations etc)

3)in reference to number (2), is it compatible with my model?and if it is,can i have the "clean install instructions" for my model (vpccw16fg) ?

4)having problems with my current OS (win 7 home premium 64bit) pre installed from sony and i would love to delete/uninstall win 7 because it is giving me a lot of headaches ie bsod..

THANKS!

Comment: I have the Sony VAIO VPC-CB15FG (the model before yours?) and it currently dual-boots Microsoft Windows 8/Ubuntu 14.04 LTS ("Trusty Tahr") without issue... The only thing you'll really need to configure is the switchable graphics, but there's plenty of threads here and in the Ubuntu forums that tell you how to do that (it's easier than you'd think).

Answer (score 0):

In brief Ubuntu will just work perfect with your model. I used to have same series model and I enjoy it...

Moreover, you can just try Ubuntu without installing. You can see this option while booting from the Ubuntu DVD. This will show you if your system will work with Ubuntu or not. But I can say you all your hardwware is compatible with it.

You can install it alongside your Windows if you really care about, or you can just remove Windows totally and work on Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks..will try and update more later...thank you again..

Answer (score 0):

See my comment above regarding compatibility...

--

Whilst you still have Microsoft Windows installed on your computer or FROM a Microsoft Windows computer, download Ubuntu ( http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop ), burn the Ubuntu "image" to DVD ( http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows ) or create a bootable "thumb" drive ( http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows ), insert your DVD or "thumb" drive and restart your computer...

The Ubuntu setup should start automatically - select "install" and then follow the instructions ( http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop ) - if you want to single-boot Ubuntu, you want to select "Replace Windows 7 with Ubuntu" at point four ( http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop ).

You don't need an Internet connection during setup, but it will ensure that you have the latest software and updates if you do (I usually recommend a wired Internet connection for setup, where possible).

It sounds like a lot of work, but it's a LOT easier than you'd think... Take your time, read the information at those links, print-out any of that information you think you will need (or bookmark the link on your mobile device) and if you still get stuck, don't be afraid to come back here...